# Infinite series representation of exponential non base e

Tags: sequences-and-series

I’m curious if there’s an infinite series representation of something like 10^x without using the log function in the series. Anyone know?

Comment: What do you mean? It is trivial that

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} a^x = a^x \cdot \ln^n(a)$$

so you're definitely not going to get a series without logarithms by using Taylor/etc. series. That doesn't prevent another means, but it does raise the question (to me at least) of why would you want a series without the logarithm, knowing that it could well be more complicated as a result? And in particular, other than the logarithm not being there, is there anything specific you want in the series expansion?

Comment: Hello, thank you.  I understand that the logarithm will be there i guess i was hoping for a simplified version of the sum with the logarithm’s sum substituted in.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer --- just tagging you so you see that I replied

Comment: So, some sort of double summation, then?